# Run rsync only if target directory exists?

Tags: rsync

I have a secondary backup drive that is usually stored offsite, but sometimes mounted. I'd like to put something in a crontab that automatically clones my backup drive to the secondary backup if it's mounted. I know that I could do something like:

```
if [ -d $target_dir ]; then rsync -a --delete $src_dir $target_dir; fi
```

but I'm wondering if there's a way to ask rsync the same thing, without resorting to a shell script? Given that it has 6.02*10^23 command line options, you'd think so...

Comment: Not to make your job harder, but if you have udev available, maybe have it run the rsync when it notices the drive being attached?

Comment: Why don't you run the command regardless? rsync will simply fail if the hard drive is not mounted.

Comment: Nice use of Avogadro's number.  :)

Comment: @Katu, wouldn't it attempt to create a directory in the root filesystem?

Comment: @JeffSchaller That's a good idea, but I want it to run in the middle of the night when I'm sure the backups aren't running, and to do so daily until I dismount the drive.

Comment: If you don't mind it erroring out you can do something like `rsync /src/. /target/.`  The trailing `/.` on the path will cause it to error out if the directory doesn't exist.

Comment: @ScottDeerwester as Zoredache said, it will cause a `No such file or directory` error.

Comment: I don't see an issue with doing it the way our are doing it already, with a `-d` test for the target directory.  What's the issue with this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick that would probably work ... In my example, rsync will succeed if $target_dir is on the 'remote' machine (localhost), else fail (by not running the remote rsync).

i.e.

`src_dir=/etc;target_dir=/test/a;rsync -azp --rsync-path="[[ -d $target_dir ]] && rsync" $src_dir localhost:$target_dir`

The failure result code should be 12 if the remote directory doesn't exist ... because it never actually ran the remote rsync due to the failure of `"[[ -d $target_dir ]]"`

`12     Error in rsync protocol data stream`

The caveat is you've got to use a TCP socket to get it to work, which may be slower.

Another option, via `/etc/crontab` (that wouldn't require a script), would be something like ..

`50 23 * * * root (src_dir="/test/src_dir"; target_dir="/test/target_dir"; [ -d $src_dir ] && [ -d $target_dir ] && rsync -a -v --delete ${src_dir}/ ${target_dir}/) &>> /var/log/test.log`